# Migrate TFVC repository from one VSTS instance to another VSTS instance

Tags: version-control, azure-devops, tfvc

I need to move, or copy, a TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) repository from one instance of VSTS (e.g.: source.visualstudio.com) to another instance of VSTS (e.g.: destination.visualstudio.com).

I thought this would fairly straightforward, but I can only find information in regards to TFS (Team Foundation Server), not VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services). Or samples that convert to a Git repository, while I need to go from TFVC to TFVC.

I am not interested in migrating Work Items at this time, just the source code and its history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No built-in tool to do it, there is a similar user voice: [make it possible to move a Team Project between Team Project Collections](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2037613-make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te)

Regarding 3rd tool, you can try it with [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility).

On the other hand, you may [change account owner of VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/change-account-ownership-vs?view=vsts) if just need to change owner.

Comment: Are there any instructions on how to change the account owner of Azure Devops (formerly VSTS) from my Microsoft Account to my Azure AD account with the same email address?

Comment: We actually went with the commercial version of OpsHub. The results were not a perfect copy (dates were changed to the time of migration), but overall the results were actable. This option did take a fair bit of setup time and the commercial version was a modest amount of money (based on the size and complexity of the instances being migrated).