# Move repos to other project

Tags: azure-devops

During the years, i wrongly used Visualstudioonline (now Azure DevOPs).
I created a project (believing that this was a repo) and then create a folder on each where i stored the various project.
Now i would like to separate these folder and create a Project for each folder.

**Is there a way to migrate/move the single folder (with all its history) to new project ?** 
The sources are now in azure devops version control, and the new project has to be in the same version control and i don't want to create GIT repo.

From the webserver that there is import feature under the project, but the tools only convert from TFVC version to GIT  and not from TFVC to TFVC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move TFVC code from one collection to another including history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518202/move-tfvc-code-from-one-collection-to-another-including-history)

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same boat the way in which I am doing it as follows:

1. Create the new repo
2. Clone existing repo to my pc
3. Checkout all branches
4. Add new repo as a remote to my local repo
5. Push the repo to the new remote
6. Go through and clean up the repo

Yes it is painful but the way im doing it is as I'm working on the project.

The other option would be to fork the repo but I haven't found a way to server the fork link.

Comment: I'll try Hugh LIn suggestion, otherwise i will create new projects, and push latest version, loosing history.

Comment: you still maintain your git history

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is currently no built-in function to migrate from tfvc to tfvc.

You can try using a third-party tool [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility) to do this.

A contributor has successfully implemented this feature with this third-party tool.For details please refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322798/migrate-tfvc-repository-from-one-vsts-instance-to-another-vsts-instance).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Tks for suggestion

Comment: Hoping your try result. : )